# Does the inequality $ \sqrt{a+b}\geq \sqrt{a/2}+\sqrt{b/2}$ have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

This is somewhat embarrassing but if $a,b$ are nonnegative real numbers the following seems to hold
$$
\sqrt{a+b}\geq \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}.
$$
Does this inequality have a name?

Comment: Easy to show using AM-GM. A "special case" can we call it?

Comment: thanks, that's what I figured.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From AM-GM
$$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab} \iff\\
a+b\geq  \frac{a+b}{2}+2\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{b}{2}} \iff\\
a+b\geq \left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}\right)^2 \overset{a,b\geq0}{\iff}\\
\sqrt{a+b}\geq \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}$$
Which makes it a special case or corollary of it.

Comment: I might prefer *consequence* or *corollary*

Comment: @Henry, yes indeed, it reads better.

Comment: As a closer look at the proof shows, it is **equivalent** to AM-GM.

Comment: Well - equivalent to the two-variable, unweighted version of AM-GM.

Answer (score 9):

If we divide by $\sqrt 2$, the inequality becomes
$$
   \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}} \ge \frac{\sqrt{\vphantom b a} + \sqrt{b}}{2}
$$
which is true because $\sqrt x$ is concave. (You can call this Jensen's inequality, though since we're only averaging $2$ points, it's just a special case of the definition of concavity.)

Answer (score 3):

Squaring both sides we obtain

$$
\sqrt{a+b}\geq \sqrt{a/2}+\sqrt{b/2} \iff a+b\ge \frac{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}2\iff \frac {a+b}2\ge \sqrt{ab}
$$

which is true by AM-GM and squaring again we obtain

$$\iff \frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4}\ge ab \iff a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2 \ge 0$$

which is a more foundamental result.